# ошибка ffmpeg при получении видео с камеры

Tags: ffmpeg

Через vlc открываю rtsp-поток: rtsp://user:password@server:5541/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/101
vlc все корректно отображает

Выполняю команду

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://user:password@server:5541/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/101 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f image2pipe pipe:1
```

Результат:

```
fmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[rtsp @ 0x1f674c0] UDP timeout, retrying with TCP
[rtsp @ 0x1f674c0] method PAUSE failed: 551 Option not supported
[rtsp @ 0x1f674c0] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264, none): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
rtsp://admin:SS8888888888@212.32.206.186:5541/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/101: could not find codec parameters
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://admin:SS8888888888@212.32.206.186:5541/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/101':
  Metadata:
    title           : Media Presentation
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264, none, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
Output #0, image2pipe, to 'pipe:1':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Причем с другой камеры ffmpeg все отлично забирает и выводит в stdout кадры в виде jprg-изображений

В чем может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте `-rtsp_transport tcp` самым первым параметром.